# use nested Query in ESQL on Message Broker

Tags: message-queue, ibm-mq, messagebroker

I use this query to find my information in Oracle and it's correctly worked : `SELECT A.ACTIONID,A.ACTIONNAME,A.ALLOWWRITE,A.ALLOWREAD FROM  THP.TBACTION  A WHERE A.ACTIONID   IN ( SELECT AP.ACTIONID FROM THP.TBACTION_PROFILE  AP WHERE  AP.PROFID IN(SELECT P.PROFID FROM THP.TBPROFILE  P WHERE P.PROFID IN(SELECT U.PROFID FROM  THP.TBUSER  U WHERE U.USERID=2 )));`

but Now I want use this Query in IBM MESSAGE BROKER on compute Node by ESQL

what do you suggest? 
can u please Introduce suitable solution for this question or write theirs syntax...

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for nesting itself is the same, but the query syntax is a bit different. Instead of writing `FROM THP.TBACTION A` you should write `FROM Database.THP.TBACTION AS A`.
You can find the reference here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.mft.doc%2Fac06000_.htm

And you should make sure you have specified the data source in the Data source property of the Compute Node.